# ngui dynamic text advice (from a noob)

Tags: dynamic, unityscript, ngui

Sorry in advance, this is an extremely noobie question (but i'm just getting into NGUI with unityscript and can't find many answers/tutorials/docs).. Also my untiyscript skills are sub-par.
I have a TCG/Playing card game object with some basic RPG stats (strength, dexterity) that currently display on the card in GUIlabel and trying to convert this to NGUI. I'm adding a UILabel as a child to the card (which contains the stats script)

Looking for some advice on going about this, the only way I've even remotely gotten something to display correctly is, unfortunately I have to attach the stats script to the label too:

```
var strLbl : UILabel;

function Start() {
    var strLbl = GetComponent(UILabel);
}

function OnGUI() {
    strLbl.text = strength.ToString();
}
```

1. This is throwing numberous 'nullreferenceexception: object reference not set to an instance of an object (for the stats script)
2. Do I need to make a separate label for each stat or is there a way
   to aggregate it into one label? (seems when I try to add strength
   ,then dexterity it overrides it)
3. is OnGUI the correct course for NGUI or is there a more efficient
   function?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this script attached to the object that the UILabel is on? You should do a check for 
   `if(strLbl != null)
        strLbl.text = strength.ToString();`
2. You could aggregate them into one label (though if individual stats update I would advise against it), assuming you want each stat on a newline then your next would be: `strLbl.text += "\n" + dexterity.ToString()`
3. No need to use OnGUI with NGUI. Especially not for setting things. You probably want to do this whole stage in Start() and have another method called for updating the label.